# local versus global rbenv versions | bundle does not use rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos, bundle, rbenv, osx-server

I'm trying to install Gitlab on OSX Server, following directions for https://github.com/CiTroNaK/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X

I'm new to ruby so flame me if i made beginner's mistake... but i ended up with complete Ruby installations in both /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448 as 
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448

Can i delete one of the two? I'm low on resources.

Furthermore... my bundle command still uses the OSX supplied Ruby:

```
macserver:~ admin$ ls -l `which ruby`
-rwxr-xr-x  8 admin  staff  410 Sep 30 18:47 /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby*

macserver:~ admin$ ls -l `which bundle`
-rwxr-xr-x  1 admin  admin  419 Sep 18 18:05 /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/bundle*

macserver:~ admin$ bundle --version
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
from /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/bundle:18
```

where did i go wrong?

Comment: it is safe to remove one of the directories, probably  ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448.

can you tell me if you are running something like this in your profile?
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

also what is the output of "echo $RBENV_ROOT" ?

Comment: i cancelled my project, just using plain Git now :(. as response to you: RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv. and i have this in my profile: "if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi"

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619964/bundle-install-not-using-rbenv-local-ruby-version